# How to Scrape Website Usage/User Data for a Website that Does Not Have an API

Tags: python, data, data-science-model, web-scraping

I am an aspiring Data Analyst and I was wondering how do I web scrape website usage/user data such as:

- total people who visited that website,
- total visitors per page,
- how long did each visitor stay on each page, etc.

The website I am interested in scraping does not have an API in case that effects your answer. I have searched online, watched many YouTube tutorials, etc., but it doesn't pertain to the data I need.

I don't know the terminology (the words) I would use to get the usage data above. I don't know where this sort of data lives on websites and if it's even accessible to the general public?

I have used the code below in Python using BeautifulSoup and urllib.request but I don't know if this is the right way to go about getting the usage/user data in particular because it's not the the typical data that I have typically scraped like:

print('title, nav, href, etc...')

Below is the code I use when I am scraping data for things like: title, nav, href, etc.

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request 

source = urllib.request.urlopen(“the website you are scraping”).read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, ‘lxml’)

print(soup)
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Web scraping will only work for data that is available on the webpage itself. Since the data you are looking for is not stored on the webpage but is more likely to be tracked by some sort of analytics software on the backend you won't be able to get this data unless the website is yours.